# Why is Googletrans unable to decode my the input?

Tags: python-3.x, googletrans

I have a JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) for a string of words that I want to run through the googletrans module. My code looks like this. Can someone tell me how can I troubleshoot this error and prevent future occurrences?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator
import csv
import re

url = "http://dpr.go.id/berita"

webpage_response = requests.get(url)
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

headers = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"bl-title mb10"})
for header in headers:
    title = header.get_text()
    translator = Translator()
    translation_title = str(translator.translate(title, dest="en").text)
    print(translation_title)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f0b1d99e5c27> in <module>
      2     title = header.get_text()
      3     translator = Translator()
----> 4     translation_title = str(translator.translate(title, dest="en").text)
      5     print(translation_title)
      6 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     79         r = self.session.get(url, params=params)
     80 
---> 81         data = utils.format_json(r.text)
     82         return data
     83
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? at what line do you get the error?

Comment: @Ron Serruya at the translation_title line.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, you got an error since the googletrans library got a bad response from google translate

Comment: @Ron Serruya What do you mean by bad response? And how can I prevent this?